# Draw circle on google maps by passing parameters to the url

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I would like to draw a circle as an overlay on the given google maps url. This is without using the google maps API. Hence, i would like to know if this can be achieved bu just passing certain parameters to the maps url.

The url i'm using is

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=M5J&sensor=false&output=embed
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately this cannot be done using URL parameters, you have to use the Google Maps API. Here is a list of [available URL parameters](http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters).