# Google Maps url how to define circular marker?

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.forms, google-maps-markers, google-maps-urls

I want to open the default maps app but instead of the default marker i want a circular marker.

this is what i have...

```
case Device.Android:
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_imovel.Endereco.Freguesia))
    {
        uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" + _imovel.Endereco.Freguesia);
    }
    else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_imovel.Endereco.Concelho)){
        uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=" + _imovel.Endereco.Concelho);
    }
    Device.OpenUri(uri);
break;
```

[image: what i have]

and this is what i want

[image: what i want]

Any hints?

Comment: There is an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13389454) for a similar question, which reads that this can only be done through the Google Maps API.

Comment: @raratiru is there a way to use Google Maps API v2 opening the google maps app instead of embedding it in my app?